# keras image classifier model configuration

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to learn image classification using Keras and TensorFlow.
I am referring to https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats problem.

My Code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# # Cats and Dogs Identification Kaggle
# 
# https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

# ## Tensorflow and GPU Memory Config

# In[14]:


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D,  Reshape, BatchNormalization
from keras import backend as K 


# tf.reset_default_graph()
# tf.set_random_seed(42)
# tf.config.set_per_process_memory_growth(True)
# tf.config.gpu.set_per_process_memory_fraction(0.4)
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=2048)])
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)

print('Keras image_data_format {}'.format(K.image_data_format()))    
print('if keras image_data_format is channel_last means data should be loaded in 32X32X3 dimensions')


# In[2]:


import os
import shutil
from shutil import copyfile
from random import seed
from random import random

def createPathIfNoExists(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)


cats_dir = '/cats'
dogs_dir = '/dogs'

source_images = '/home/user/Desktop/dogs_cat_keras'
data_dir = source_images + '/data'

train_dir = data_dir + '/train'
train_cats_dir = train_dir + cats_dir
train_dogs_dir = train_dir + dogs_dir

validation_dir = data_dir + '/validation'
validation_cats_dir = validation_dir + cats_dir
validation_dogs_dir = validation_dir + dogs_dir




createPathIfNoExists(data_dir)

createPathIfNoExists(train_dir)
createPathIfNoExists(train_cats_dir)
createPathIfNoExists(train_dogs_dir)

createPathIfNoExists(validation_dir)
createPathIfNoExists(validation_cats_dir)
createPathIfNoExists(validation_dogs_dir)

print('Source directory {}'.format(source_images))
print('Data directory {}'.format(data_dir))
print('train directory {}'.format(train_dir))
print('train cats directory {}'.format(train_cats_dir))
print('train dogs directory {}'.format(train_dogs_dir))
print('validation directory {}'.format(validation_dir))
print('validation directory {}'.format(validation_cats_dir))
print('validation directory {}'.format(validation_dogs_dir))



# inputFiles = source_images + '/train'

# cats = [inputFiles+'/' + d for d in os.listdir(inputFiles) if d.startswith('cat')]

# print('All cats count {}'.format(len(cats)))

# dogs = [inputFiles+'/' + d for d in os.listdir(inputFiles) if d.startswith('dog')]

# print('All dogs count {}'.format(len(dogs)))

# data_split_70 = 8400 

# train_cats = cats[:data_split_70]
# validation_cats = cats[data_split_70:]


# train_dogs = dogs[:data_split_70]
# validation_dogs = dogs[data_split_70:]

# print('Total train cats {} and validation cats {}'.format(len(train_cats), len(validation_cats)))
# print('Total train dogs {} and validation dogs {}'.format(len(train_dogs), len(validation_dogs)))

# # Put train cats data in train directory
# for item in train_cats: 
#     if os.path.isfile(item):
#         shutil.copyfile(item, train_cats_dir + '/' + os.path.basename(item))

# # Put validation cats data in validation directory
# for item in validation_cats:
#     if os.path.isfile(item):
#         shutil.copyfile(item, validation_cats_dir + '/' + os.path.basename(item))

# # Put train cats data in train directory
# for item in train_dogs:
#     if os.path.isfile(item):
#         shutil.copyfile(item, train_dogs_dir + '/' + os.path.basename(item))

# # Put validation cats data in validation directory
# for item in validation_dogs:
#     if os.path.isfile(item):
#         shutil.copyfile(item, validation_dogs_dir + '/' + os.path.basename(item))    


# ## General imports

# In[15]:


import datetime
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

import h5py


# ## Data Import

# In[16]:


dataGenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40,
                                  width_shift_range=0.2,
                                  height_shift_range=0.2,
                                  shear_range=0.2,
                                  zoom_range=0.2,
                                  horizontal_flip=True,
                                  fill_mode='nearest')


# ### Image Display

# In[17]:


img = load_img('/home/user/Desktop/dogs_cat_keras/data/train/cats/cat.12467.jpg')  # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (width X height X 3)
print(x.shape)
# print(type(img))
# print(img.size)
# print(img.mode)
plt.imshow(x/255)
plt.show()
print('Shape before reshape {}'.format(x.shape))

## Generate data = 0
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (1, width, height, 3)
print('Shape after reshape {}'.format(x.shape))


# ### Generate augumented data using image generator

# In[6]:


# import os

# augumented_data_path = data_path + '/preview'

# if not os.path.exists(augumented_data_path):
#     os.mkdir(augumented_data_path)

# i = 0
# for batch in dataGenerator.flow(x, batch_size=1,
#                           save_to_dir=augumented_data_path, save_prefix='cat', save_format='jpeg'):
#     i += 1
#     if i > 20:
#         break  # otherwise the generator would loop indefinitely


# ### Building Graph 

# In[23]:


img_width, img_height = 150, 150
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3) 

nnModel = Sequential()

nnModel.add(Flatten(input_shape=(input_shape)))
nnModel.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
nnModel.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
nnModel.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


# ### Compile function

# In[26]:


nnModel.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


# ### Train Generator

# In[20]:


batch_size = 32

train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255,
                                    shear_range=0.2,
                                    zoom_range=0.2,
                                    horizontal_flip=True)
train_generator = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),  # all images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')

print('Train path {}'.format(train_dir))

test_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255)

print('Test path {}'.format(validation_dir))

validation_generator = test_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,  # this is the target directory
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),  # all images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')


# In[24]:


nnModel.summary()


# ### Train

# In[27]:



nnModel.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                      steps_per_epoch=2048, 
                      epochs=64, 
                      validation_data=validation_generator, 
                      validation_steps=1024)
```

I am getting following exception

```
<ipython-input-27-59bf3c75cdc4> in <module>
      3                       epochs=64,
      4                       validation_data=validation_generator,
----> 5                       validation_steps=1024)...

A target array with shape (32, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Problem statement has lot of notebook solution, but here i don't want to use cnn for learning purpose. Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in your code comes from this line:

```
nnModel.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You have to change your loss function to `categorical_crossentropy`, not `binary_crossentropy`. Practically, in your code, you have to write     `nnModel.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`

If you have a binary classification problem, you can opt for one of these two variants:

1. `Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')` + `loss = 'binary_crossentropy`'
2. `Dense(2,activation='softmax')` + `loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'`

The only small change you may need to also make is for `ImageDataGenerator`, with the `class_mode`(set it to '`binary`' in the first case and to '`categorical`' in the second case)

Comment: Thank you timbus for your detailed explanation i am able to run the program now and  i can see accuracy/val_accuracy i will play with layers and continue my learning. Can you also point me to any tutorials whihc explains just input shape and mathematics involved in dense layers. BTW you have answerd my question.